# Django query — how to get list of dictionaries with M2M relation?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Let's say, I have this simple application with two models — `Tag` and `SomeModel`

```
class Tag(models.Model):
  text = ...

class SomeModel(models.Model):
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='tags')
```

And I want to get something like this from database:

```
[{'id': 1, 'tags': [1, 4, 8, 10]}, {'id': 6, 'tags': []}, {'id': 8, 'tags': [1, 2]}]
```

It is list of several SomeModel's dictionaries with SomeModel's id and ids of tags.

What should the Django query looks like? I tried this:

```
>>> SomeModel.objects.values('id', 'tags').filter(pk__in=[1,6,8])
[{'id': 1, 'tags': 1}, {'id': 1, 'tags': 4}, {'id': 1, 'tags': 8}, ...]
```

This is not what I want, so I tried something like this:

```
>>> SomeModel.objects.values_list('id', 'tags').filter(pk__in=[1,6,8])
[(1, 1), (1, 4), (1, 8), ...]
```

And my last try was:

```
>>> SomeModel.objects.values_list('id', 'tags', flat=True).filter(pk__in=[1,6,8])
...
TypeError: 'flat' is not valid when values_list is called with more than one field.
```

—

Maybe Django cannot do this, so the most similar result to what I want is:

```
[{'id': 1, 'tags': 1}, {'id': 1, 'tags': 4}, {'id': 1, 'tags': 8}, ...]
```

Is there any Python build-in method which transform it to this?

```
[{'id': 1, 'tags': [1, 4, 8, 10]}, {'id': 6, 'tags': []}, {'id': 8, 'tags': [1, 2]}]
```

**— EDIT:**

If I write method in `SomeModel`:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='tags')

  def get_tag_ids(self):
    aid = []
    for a in self.answers.all():
      aid.append(a.id)
    return aid
```

And then call:

```
>>> sm = SomeModel.objects.only('id', 'tags').filter(pk__in=[1,6,8])
# Hit database
>>> for s in sm:
...   s.get_tag_ids()
...
>>> # Hit database 3 times.
```

This is not working, because it access to database 4 times. I need just one access.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but have you looked at [django-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/) or [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit)? If you're not necessarily coding tags, you may be able to glean some code from them for how they handle it.

Comment: I know django-tagging, not django-taggit. Thank you, but this is just my hobby project and I want to learn Django as much as possible, so I don't want to use any third-party code.

Comment: You can always just write your own classmethod or Manager to return the data in the format you're needing.

Comment: I'm not sure how to accomplish that just by a query but couldn't you just pack the list yourself?

Comment: @Brandon Maybe method `get_tag_ids()` in SomeModel which returns list of tag's ids.

Comment: Sure. I often add my own classmethods and managers to do various things. If you're just needing to return the tag IDs for an instance of the model, just make it a property of the model class.

Comment: @Brandon I edit question and write this new method. The problem is, it hit database 4 times. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. If you make it an instance property, it's going to hit the database per instance. If you make it a classmethod or model manager, it's going to minimize the number of calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ArgsKwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/911519/argskwargs) mentioned here in comments — I write my own code, which packs the list:

```
>>> sm = SomeModel.objects.values('id', 'tags').filter(pk__in=[1,6,8])
>>> a = {}
>>> for s in sm:
...   if s['id'] not in a:
...     a[s['id']] = [s['tags'],]
...   else:
...     a[s['id']].append(s['tags'])
...
```

The output of this code is exactly what I need, and it hit database only once. But it is not very elegant, I don't like this code :)

Btw. is better use `pk` or `id` in queries? `.values('id', 'tags')` or `.values('pk', 'tags')`?

Answer (score 0):

What about a custom method on the model that returns a list of all tags

```
class Tag(models.Model):
  text = ...

class SomeModel(models.Model):
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='tags')

  def all_tags(self):
    return self.tags.values_list('pk',flat=True)
```

and then

```
SomeModel.objects.values('id', 'all_tags').filter(pk__in=[1,6,8])
```

Comment: I like this solution, too bad it is not possible. When you run this code, the exception `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'all_tags' into field. Choices are: id, tags` is raised.

Comment: to answer your question about 'pk' vs 'id';

'pk' is a shortcut that points to whatever the identity field is

if for some reason you changed your db's id field (or were working with external objects and didn't know their pk field names) 'pk' will always point to whatever the correct identity field is

as for "better" I don't know but I like 'pk' because it feels more generic and DRY